# React + Redux + Firebase simple file upload

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload files with react redux and firebase but i am stuck. This is my code:

```
const Input = (props) => (
  <input type="file" name="file-input" multiple {...props} />
)

function ProjectPage() {
  const { projectId } = useParams()
  const classes = useStyles()
  const firebase = useFirebase()

  var fileInput = [];

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(fileInput[0])
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref()
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(fileInput[0])
    return fileRef
      .then(snap => console.log('upload successful', snap))
      .catch(err => console.error('error uploading file', err))
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    fileInput = e.target.files
  }

  // Create listener for projects
  useFirebaseConnect(() => [{ path: `projects/${projectId}` }])

  // Get projects from redux state
  const project = useSelector(({ firebase: { data } }) => {
    return data.projects && data.projects[projectId]
  })


    return (
   <div className={classes.root}>
    <form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <div>
      <Input onChange={onChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </form>

  </div>
  )
}
```

Here is error that i get and console log. `console.log(fileInput[0])`
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fiZY.png)

I found out that its maybe because i need to add path to file here `"storageRef.child(fileInput[0])"` but i just dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child) the child method can only receive a `string` which is a relative path from this location to the desired child location.

It returns a reference to the child's location at the Firebase storage. The console error you're seeing tells us that the argument passed to the child wasn't a `string`.

In your case, you're setting the file object where the file name should be.
Specifically, try to change `storageRef.child(fileInput[0])` to `storageRef.child(fileInput[0].name).put(fileInput[0])`. See the [full example.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example)

Let me know if I could be more of help.

Comment: Yes i write it in the end of my problem thats this is probably problem and that i cant solve it. Because browser cant get path to file in pc and i dont know how to get over this. (still new in react and this stuff.)

Comment: Thanks it really works i was trying to do it for 12hours :D